# Doubtful about whether this is the appropriate usage of "in which"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, relative-pronouns, ielts

I've been writing essays preparing for an IELTS exam, and writing this particular paragraph i'm not 100% sure whether this is the right usage of the expression "in which".

> Whereas in the past books were the main source of knowledge, the arrival of the internet has drastically altered the relevance of books, because of the easiness ***in which*** such information can be accessed.

Is this the proper usage of the expression?

Comment: `by which` is better I would think - but _such information_ does not work here either because that does not match _main source of knowledge_. I would consider _Whereas in the past, books were the main source of knowledge, the arrival of the internet has drastically altered their relevance, due to the ease of accessing information online._

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, why "such information" does not work here? isn't it enough that it is referring to "main source of knowledge", considering that "information" here is a synonym of knowledge, or is there a rule that says that "such" should come with a direct reference of the word?

Comment: *In which* is wrong here: we speak of doing something ***with** ease*, not ***in** ease*, which suggests a mode of living rather than of acting.

Comment: "main source of knowledge" is abstract, "such information" is specific - _He listened to her explain and wondered where he also could get such information_

Answer (score 1):

You could use *by which* as @mplungian suggets but it would be more usual use *with which* giving "...the ease *(not easiness)* with which information can be accessed".

It is difficult to state a rule for this but the nearest I can come to one us that *by which* is usually associated with the method used to do something, *with which* is usually associated with the manner that something is done and *in which*, *on which*  and so on are associated with where something can be found. So you have "the method *by which* he searched", "the speed *with which* he ran", "the book *in which* I found", "the table *on which* it stood". There are a few odd uses like "the car by which he stood" but, in that case, the preposition *by* is being used in the same way as *in*. It's the same as "the car in which he sat".

Having said that there is also "the way *in which* I searched" which looks as though it should be the same as "the method *by which* he searched" or "the speed *with which* he ran" but, actually, 'way' is a not really a noun defining a process like 'method' and is not a descriptor of an action like 'speed'. As I said, stating a rule is difficult, if not impossible.